# ¿Cómo puedo añadir nuevos valores a un archivo JSON existente?

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Estoy trabajando con Node.JS, lo que quiero hacer es que, cuando el código se ejecute y la ID del usuario es inexistente en el archivo ./points.json, que sea añadido y que proceda con el aumento del puntaje. De momento, este código sólo añade puntos a aquellos usuarios que estuviesen previamente escritos en el archivo, pero no añade nuevos usuarios.

Edit: Cuando un usuario ajeno (que no ha sido escrito previamente en el archivo JSON) revisa la cantidad de puntos que tiene a través de **userData.points**, muestra 1 (no existe, entonces se añade la ID del usuario más sus valores "points" y "level", añade 1 a "points" y lo escribe en el programa, pero sin embargo, los nuevos valores no son escritos, y cuando revisas los puntos de nuevo, al no haber sido escritos, empieza de 0 y vuelve a devolver 1.

El formato del archivo ./points.json es el siguiente (ha sido escrito por este programa).

```
{"242043489611808769":{"points":22,"level":0}}
```

```js
let points = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./points.json', 'utf8'));
    
let userData = points[user.id];
if(!userData) userData = {points: 0, level: 0};
userData.points++;
let curLevel = Math.floor(0.2 * Math.sqrt(userData.points));
    
fs.writeFile('./points.json', JSON.stringify(points), function (err) {
   if (err) return console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que falta es establecer el nuevo `userData` a la estructura de datos `points`.

Algo asi,

```
if(!userData) {
  userData = {points: 0, level: 0};
  points[user.id] = userData; // <<== falta esto
}
```

Salu2