# Datos de usuario asignados únicamente a un servidor

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Anteriormente, había hecho un programa en la cual, cuando alguien mandaba un mensaje, se añadía un campo con su ID y su puntuación en un archivo JSON a través de **NodeJS** y **FS** [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39984/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-a%C3%B1adir-nuevos-valores-a-un-archivo-json-existente).

Resumen, tengo un archivo que guarda puntuaciones globales, de la siguiente manera:

```
let points = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./points.json', 'utf8'));
```

En la cual, el archivo **./points.json** tenía el siguiente formato:

```
{
 "242043489611808769":{"points":617,"level":4,"time":1482316617392},
 "129213229221019648":{"points":22,"level":0,"time":1482316617609},
 "190388892799598592":{"points":214,"level":2,"time":1482316612355}
}
```

Y los datos se añadían (en caso de ID inexistente) o se actualizaban con el siguiente código:

```
let userData = points[msg.author.id];
if(!userData) {
    userData = {points: 0, level: 0, time: msg.createdTimestamp};
    points[msg.author.id] = userData;
}
```

Pero ahora, necesito crear puntuaciones "locales", en la que se guardarían los datos con la siguiente estructura:

```
{
  "256566731684839428":[
    {"ID":"242043489611808769", "points":617},
    {"ID":"129213229221019648", "points":22},
    {"ID":"190388892799598592", "points":214},
  ]
}
```

Y defino el segundo archivo JSON como:

```
let lpoints = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./lpoints.json', 'utf8'));
```

En la que **256566731684839428** es la ID del *guild* o *servidor*. Mi problema, cuando la ID de un guild/servidor es inexistente, éste debe ser añadido, y si lo está, pero el usuario del servidor no lo está, se deben añadir el campo para el respectivo usuario y hacer los mismos procedimientos que mi programa hace con los datos de los usuarios a nivel global (escritos más arriba).

He intentado con el siguiente código para obtener los datos de los usuarios como en el nivel global (en los datos de usuario "locales" sólo necesito puntos asignados a cada ID, a diferencia de los "globales" que tienen puntos, nivel y tiempo). Y, el valor de "points" en los datos locales no tiene por qué ser el mismo para todos los servidores (para eso está el global).

```
let lguild = msg.guild.id;
let luserData = lpoints.lguild[msg.author.id];
```

Pero devuelve undefined, ¿cómo lo puedo resolver?

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teniendo este objeto: (lo descrito abajo es equivalente a cargarlos con JSON.parse)

```
var lpoints = { 
  "256566731684839428":[
    {"ID":"242043489611808769", "points":617},
    {"ID":"129213229221019648", "points":22},
    {"ID":"190388892799598592", "points":214},
  ]
}
```

#### Obtener los datos

Te explico el formato JSON y como se lee/escribe en javascript dicho formato:

Un bloque encerrado entre `{ }` es un objeto. Es decir, que los elementos se identifican por un nombre. Para acceder a los elementos del objeto usar la notacion

```
lpoints[nombre]  // donde nombre es la clave a obtener o establecer el valor
```

En la este caso sería :

```
var guild = lpoints["256566731684839428"]
```

Ahora lo que esta encerrado entre `[ ]` es un array, por lo tanto, como ese array tiene elementos encerrados entre `{}`, resulta que `guild` es un: array de objetos.

Para acceder a los elementos de este array (los objetos) debes utilizar su indice (el primer elemento tiene indice 0)

```
var user1 = guild[1]   // devueve {"ID":"129213229221019648", "points":22}
user1.points = 25;
```

#### Agregar nuevos datos

Para agregar datos al objeto `guild` debes usar la misma notación que tienes hasta ahora, pero si quieres usar un array (como el otro guild), simplemente pon un `[]` en la asignacion lo que agregara el arreglo como un nuevo `guild`.

```
lpoints["NUEVO CODIGO"] = [] // esto agrega un array vacio.
```

Luego para agregar elementos a este nuevo `guild` debes usar el metodo `push` del array.

```
var nuevoGuild = lpoints["NUEVO CODIGO"];  // obtenemos lo agregado antes.
nuevoGuild.push({ ID: "12312321321321321", "points" : 0});
```

### Buscar un ID dentro de un `guild`.

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, te recomiendo `find`. La funcion find ejecuta la función callback una vez por cada elemento presente el arreglo hasta que encuentre uno en donde el callback retorne un valor true. Si tal elemento es encontrado, find inmediatamente retorna el valor del elemento.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
var userX = guild.find( function(elemento) {
  // retornara el elemento que 
  return elemento.ID === "242043489611808769"
});
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50571/discussion-on-answer-by-rnd-datos-de-usuario-asignados-unicamente-a-un-servidor).